# Retrieve Innermost value inside one-line 2 for loops?

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to get the value of j when name matches in i. But unfortunately all I am getting is the last element in Functions(). I guess this makes sense. But how is it possible to get value of j at the time name matches the list of GetFunctionName()'s?

Is there any one line code to do this?

```
func_ea = [j for i in [GetFunctionName(j) for j in Functions()] if name in i]
```

EDIT:  Thanks eric for the solving the first problem
Would it be possible to reduce this further down to one liners?

```
def LocateBytesInFunctions(self, searchterm, *funcname):
    foundaddress = []

    for name in funcname:
        func_ea = [i for i in Functions() if name in GetFunctionName(i)]
        for startea in func_ea:
            endea = GetFunctionAttr(startea, FUNCATTR_END)
            self.debugprint("Start: " + hex(startea) + " End: " + hex(endea))
            foundaddress.extend(self.LocateBytes(searchterm, startea, endea))
    return foundaddress`
```

Comment: Can you write this code without list comprehensions? I'm not 100% sure what isn't working here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `i` is only used in one place, you can expand the inner comprehension:

```
func_ea = [j for j in Functions() if name in GetFunctionName(j)]
```

Comment: Thank you Eric,

This is much better. I didn't even realize it

Answer (score 0):

The inner comprehension is running to completion, so `j` is getting bound to the last result from `Functions()`. One way to fix this is to keep both `j` and `GetFunctionName(j)` around so that you can reference it later in the comprehension loop.

```
func_ea = [j for i, j in [(GetFunctionName(j), j) for j in Functions()]
             if name in i]
```